# Curves matching libraries and service

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning

I have some images like below

[image]

Now I need build a website allow user draw some line on white board, and then the website return images which is most similar with or contain curves of user drawn.

A user image like this

[image]

So, are there some libraries or services to implement that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "are there some libraries or services to implement that?" Sorry you are in wrong place!

Comment: You can build your own using **template matching**